# Queryable, Dynamic Textures in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I'm building a farming sim, and am trying to simulate soil quality as a part of the simulation.  If soil quality is a scalar over the 2d surface of the terrain, it seems to me that I should be able to represent it just as an invisible B/W texture, with each pixel representing the soil quality at a given location.

The soil quality should effect how well plants grow, and should change as a function of time and user input, so I also need to be able to query and change the values of this texture every frame.

Is this something I can do in Unity?

Where should I start trying to implement this?

Comment: Will the soil be made as "terrain" or as individual objects in the game? This has great relevance for what options might apply

Comment: I was thinking that the soil would be made as terrain, but I guess I'm open to other options. Individual objects seems like it would be potentially too complex.

Comment: Depends on the design of your game. If its blocky or square'ish then it might be easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

As for detecting soil quality. If the soil will be part of a terrain object. You should be able to get a working solution if you detect the texture type used at a given position as per the guide in this link: https://gamedevbeginner.com/terrain-footsteps-in-unity-how-to-detect-different-textures/

You can then try "paint" the terrain texture values as per the guide in this link, to reflect updating soil quality: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1743422/paint-terrain-texture-on-runtime.html

Comment: You could also try look into how some people implement adding snow to their landscapes. Terrain shaders and such I believe might be used there, althought never looked into how terrain snow is added, just saw it used in some asset store packs.